# Como se decide se uma aplicação está em alfa, beta, RC ou RTM?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, versionamento, convenções-de-nome

Cada Windows tem versões alfa, beta, RC e RTM, sendo que conforme se avança da esquerda pra direita nessas versões ele vai ficando mais "pronto". Quanto a RC e RTM, não sei se isso se usa em outros softwares, mas em geral se usa falar sobre versões alfa e beta. Eu sei também que não se pula diretamente de um pra outro. Não é porque começa em alfa que a próxima versão é beta, tanto que existem alfa 1, alfa 2, etc.

De qualquer forma, fico me perguntando, como se toma decisões quanto a isso? Como se faz pra saber se um software está em alfa, beta, RC ou RTM? Quais são os critérios que se usa pra determinar isso?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Origem

Estas nomenclaturas começaram ser usados após a IBM classificar seus hardwares como A, B ou C de acordo com o estágio que o produto estava<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release)</sup>. Depois os softwares começaram a ter terminologia semelhante mas usando letras gregas no lugar. Outros fornecedores gostaram da ideia e começaram adotar estas e novas nomenclaturas para fases de desenvolvimento/lançamento de produtos.

## Marketing

Cada um decide o que é melhor para si. Nunca vi uma regra clara de quando cada uma deve ser usada. É certo que dificilmente uma organização especifica seja claramente melhor do que a outra, até porque é mais uma nomenclatura, um instrumento de comunicação dos lançamentos. O mais importante é ser consistente no projeto. Os seus usuários precisam saber o que cada nome significa para o seu projeto. Isto tem pouco a ver com a organização do projeto, com o versionamento em si. É bem menos uma técnica de engenharia e mais uma **técnica de marketing**.

## Como escolher uma estratégia

Você pode estabelecer metas e objetivos para cada fase. Em alguns casos o que define a passagem de uma fase para outra é uma data estabelecida. Mas o mais comum é atingir um certo nível de maturidade e/ou o estabelecimento que determinadas tarefas ou atualizações não mais serão aceitas.

Estas nomenclaturas raramente são usadas em projetos menores, principalmente internos a uma empresa.

Vou me basear no artigo [liberação de software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle) da Wikipedia.

## Pré-alfa

Refere-se a todas as atividades realizadas durante o projeto de software anteriores aos testes. Tais atividades podem incluir análise de requisitos, projeto de software, desenvolvimento e teste de unidade.

Em um desenvolvimento típico de código aberto, há várias versões pré-alfa. Versões chamadas *milestone* incluem conjuntos específicos de funções, e são lançadas tão logo a funcionalidade esteja implementada. Em código fechado não é comum que o público tenha acesso a estas versões.

## Alfa

Primeira fase em que iniciam-se os testes — o alfa é a primeira letra do alfabeto grego, também usada como o número 1. Nesta fase, os desenvolvedores geralmente realizam testes caixa-branca. Validações adicionais são feitas com testes caixa-preta por uma equipe específica de testes.

Softwares alfa podem ser instáveis e provocar travamentos ou perda de dados. A exceção é quando o alfa é publicamente disponibilizado, situação em que os desenvolvedores focam mais na estabilidade, de modo que os testes possam ser feitos mais extensivamente. Em projetos fechados a publicação de softwares em versão alfa, entretanto, não é comum. Embora isto esteja mudando. Ou o conceito todo esteja mudando.

Já é comum vermos lançamentos alfa, algumas vezes chamados de *milestone* ou CTP (*Community Technology Preview). Estes lançamentos costumam ser mais confiáveis e fogem da ideia original dos lançamentos alfa, mas também não costumam ser exatamente um beta já que o projeto ainda está em estado que permite muitas alterações fundamentais.

## Beta

Beta, segunda letra do alfabeto grego e representativa do número 2, dá nome à fase posterior à alfa. Geralmente inicia-se quando não há mais funcionalidades destrutivas a serem implementadas no software. O foco na versão beta é reduzir impactos aos usuários, geralmente incorporando testes de usabilidade. O processo de liberação de uma versão beta é chamado liberação beta e, tipicamente, é sua primeira divulgação pública, fora dos limites da organização que o desenvolve.

Os usuários de versões beta são chamados *beta testers* ("testadores beta"). Geralmente este grupo compõe-se de consumidores prospectivos que aceitam participar dos testes sem serem pagos por isso, embora muitas vezes ganhem descontos ou algum tipo de compensação, ou mesmo recebam o software de graça.

As versões betas são muito utilizadas como demonstrações dentro da organização e para clientes externos. Alguns desenvolvedores referem-se a esta versão como *preview*, *technical preview* ou *early access* ("acesso adiantado"). Em alguns casos estas versões são lançadas em um estado mais próximo do alfa.

Alguns softwares são mantidos em beta perpétuo. O que dá mais liberdade para os desenvolvedores trabalharem e evita certos compromissos.

Em projetos de código fechado é comum dividir o beta em:

- fechado - restrito a um grupo de usuários escolhidos pelo desenvolvedor;
- aberto - liberado para todos que desejem participar do teste.

Em projetos menos conhecidos é comum ter apenas esta fase (ou nem esta) nomeada antes da liberação oficial.

## Release candidate

O termo *release candidate* ("candidato a lançamento"), ou simplesmente RC, refere-se a uma versão com potencial para ser o produto final, pronta para ser lançada a menos que algum *bug* sério apareça. Neste estágio de estabilização do produto, todas as funcionalidades encontram-se especificadas, implementadas e testadas através de uma ou mais fases beta sem a ocorrência de *bugs* sérios.

Ultimamente tenho visto o uso do termo mesmo em casos que normalmente eram considerados beta.

O termo "golden master" também é usado para designar esta fase, e o último *golden master* é utilizado como versão final. Outras letras do alfabeto grego, como gama e delta, são usadas para indicar versões substancialmente completas, mas ainda em fase de testes, com ômega ou zênite para versões finais de teste e tidas como livres de *bugs*, prontas para produção.

Um lançamento é nomeado *code complete* ("código completo") quando a equipe de desenvolvimento concorda que a versão não terá a inclusão de nenhum código fonte adicional, embora ainda possa haver mudanças no código para corrigir defeitos. Pode ainda haver mudança na documentação ou nos arquivos de dados, ou no código utilizado para testes.

Em alguns casos acabam funcionando como um demo antecipado do produto.

## RTM

Os termos *release to manufacturing* ("lançamento para a fabricação") ou *release to marketing* ("lançamento para o mercado"), ambos abreviados como RTM, são utilizados quando o software está pronto para o consumidor final. As iniciais RTM são tipicamente usadas em certos contextos em que há produção para um grande público, em oposição a softwares de público mais restrito — como softwares para finalidades específicas ou governamentais —, notavelmente naqueles distribuídos com componentes de hardware ou vendidos em grandes redes de lojas.

## GA

O termo *general availability* ("disponibilização geral") é o ponto onde todas as atividades de comercialização necessárias foram completadas e o software foi disponibilizado para o mercado, seja pela internet ou em mídias físicas.

Atividades comerciais podem incluir a disponibilidade geográfica do produto, a tradução em várias línguas de acordo com os mercados-alvo e a finalização de testes de segurança. O tempo entre a RTM e a GA pode ir de semanas a meses, dependendo da demanda comercial exigida pela GA.

Esta é a fase em que o produto é considerado "vivo" — é a versão final. Tal versão é tida como muito estável e relativamente livre de *bugs*, com uma qualidade aceitável para todos os usuários finais. Em jogos, esta versão também é conhecida como *gold* ("ouro").

Também pode ser conhecido como RTW (*Release to web*). Cada vez é mais comum os lançamentos gerais serem feitos abertamente na web.

Algumas versões podem ser classificadas como *long term support* ("suporte de longa duração"), ou LTS, o que lhes dá a garantia de serem atualizáveis para a próxima LTS e desfrutarem de suporte pelo fabricante por um tempo mais longo que versões não-LTS.

## EOL

*End of life* ("fim de vida") ou *end of line* ("fim de linha") é outro marco usado também para indicar quando uma versão não será mais suportada ou pelo menos não terá o suporte garantindo nos mesmos moldes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futur](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md)a.