# Quando usar "0.x.x" e "alpha" em versionamentos?

Tags: versionamento

Conforme o site http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/

> Dado um número de versão *MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH*, incremente a:
>
> - versão Maior(MAJOR): quando fizer mudanças incompatíveis na API
> - versão Menor(MINOR): quando adicionar funcionalidades mantendo compatibilidade
> - versão de Correção(PATCH): quando corrigir falhas mantendo compatibilidade.
>
> Rótulos adicionais para pré-lançamento(pre-release) e metadados de construção(build) estão disponíveis como extensão ao formato *MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.*.

Lendo esse trecho no FAQ:

> Como devo lidar com revisões na fase 0.y.z de desenvolvimento inicial?
>
> A coisa mais simples a se fazer é começar sua versão de desenvolvimento inicial em 0.1.0 e, então, incrementar a uma versão ‘menor’ em cada lançamento subsequente.
>
> Como eu sei quando lançar a versão 1.0.0?
>
> Se seu software está sendo usado em produção, ele já deve ser provavelmente 1.0.0. Se você possui uma API estável a qual usuários passaram a depender, deve ser 1.0.0. Se você está se preocupando bastante com compatibilidade com versões anteriores, já deve ser 1.0.0.

Eu entendi o que o 0.x.x é somente para desenvolvimento e quando estiver estável então devemos migrar para 1.0.0, mas o que eu não entendi é como isto funciona junto com o Alpha, Beta e RC. No caso Alpha e Beta não são estabilizados ainda, apenas talvez o RC (Release Candidate).

Pelo que entendi Alpha é geralmente "distribuído" entre os desenvolvedores ou um grupo que irá experimentar.

As duvidas:

- Quando usar `-alpha` e quando usar 0.x.x?
- Os sufixos Alpha, Beta e RC são apenas para softwares comerciais (não estou falando de pagos) como softwares completos e o uso do 0.x.x seria mais voltado a códigos?

Comment: Já não responde? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/101 Ou seria baseado em opinião?

Comment: @bigown Me parece que responder como incremetar, o que parece que é o que desejo, mas não é especifico ao uso do Alpha, Beta, RC ao menos pelo que li, vou tentar ler melhor. Não acho que seja baseado em opiniões, a não ser que você me confirme que Alpha, beta, RC não são padronizados (standard), acho que minha pergunta vai mais para o lado do *"lançamento"*. Todavia obrigado por enquanto, assim que tiver um tempo vou ler sua resposta que parece esclarecedora em outros pontos.

Comment: E essa? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20999/101

Answer (score 2):

## Atualização da resposta

Algum tempo se passou e minha opinião mudou. Atualmente estou seguindo o semantic version em alguns projetos, outros não. Não existe uma regra universal para versionamento.

Dos canais, **Alpha** é um grupo privado, menor quantia de pessoas testando, as vezes testes internos e os próprios desenvolvedores. **Beta** para quando você libera gradualmente para uma parcela do seu público alvo e **Release Candidate** para quando você libera o uso para todos mas ainda quer colher informações relevantes para o lançamento da versão final.

O componente da versão, fora o canal, especifica o que está sendo trabalhado. Pode existir o `1.0.0-alpha` que passa a ser o `1.0.0-beta` e então o `1.0.0-rc`, para então `1.0.0`. Isso quando o desenvolvimento se mostrou estável e ninguém reclamou em nenhum canal.

Quando reclamarem no Beta, por exemplo, você descarta o `-rc` e passa a testar o `1.0.1-beta`, que derivou do `1.0.0-beta`. Se o problema for relatado no Alpha, você deriva a `1.0.1-alpha`. Se for relatado no Release Candidate, `1.0.1-rc`.

Isso não é regra, é umas das formas de pensar nisso. Você faz o seu próprio versionamento e segue essas regras que você mesmo criou. A Synver não consegue ser uma regra para tudo e acaba sendo mais uma especificação teórica do que prática.

Então a versão `0.1.0` pode ser a versão inicial do seu projeto, mas como só você e seu time está testando, e vocês são o único grupo de testes, use o canal `-alpha` nele. Quando começar a "tomar forma", não publique o `0.1.0` e publique diretamente o `1.0.0`, se você se sentir confortável com isso.

---

Resposta anterior:

Pelo o que o Visual Studio diz, é diferente a classificação das versões, não totalmente, mas altera algumas coisas que fazem sentido, quais é as versões *Maior, menor, compilação e revisão*, mostrando abaixo, respectivamente:

> *Major* . *Minor* . *Build* . *Revision*

Eu uso minha teoria para alterar as versões dos meus aplicativos:

- **Uma estupenda mudança:** Incremento o *Major*, geralmente em 1, também aumento quando o *Minor* está muito alto.
- **Alguns novos recursos:** Incremento o *Minor*, geralmente eu baseio o número que vou definir dependendo do recurso novo adicionado, por exemplo, se for algo muito útil e bom, incremento em 100 ou 200, se for algo pequeno, está entre 10 e 99.
- **Correções de bugs:** Incremento o *Build*, no caso a compilação, então eu também defino o tanto que vai aumentar dependendo de quantos bugs foram corrigidos.
- **Pequenas modificações ou correções:** Incremento o *Revision*, apenas uma revisãozinha no aplicativo, um erro de ortografia ou algo do tipo.

Não sei se o correto é definir um padrão de versão para todos os aplicativos por quê **esse padrão não existe**, como posso provar? Existem aplicativos com suas devidas versões (*não, os exemplos abaixo são inexistentes*):

- Aplicativo do zézin, versão 1.2.5.12
- Aplicativo do FooBar, versão 2015.2162.122.5
- Aplicativo do HelloWorld, versão 0.1262.1.25

Agora me diz, do aplicativo zézin para o FooBar, teve muita modificação em relação as suas versões, correto?

Eu uso sempre o Alpha para uma fase antes do Beta, **em meu uso,** o Alpha é sempre antes do **1.0**, após isso vem a versão **Beta**, se necessário pode ser o Beta e o Final, liberando um Beta e uma versão mais estável, no caso o Final (ou no seu caso, o RC (release)).

Quando você achar que seu aplicativo está bom, rodando liso sem bugs ou problemas, você lança um Beta, a partir do Beta vem o Final, e pode sair mais Betas e finais para sempre, **mas nunca poderá sair um Alpha após um Beta ou Final**.

Comment: Já vi softwares alpha que não eram antes do 1.0, geralmente em um nova versão. Opera e Firefox tem este costume.

Comment: Geralmente usa-se o alpha quando você quer testar alguns recursos mas conhece uma quantidade severas de bugs, geralmente você não está interessado em identificar bugs. Na versão beta, por outro lado, você considera que não há bugs e está tentando identificá-los e corrigi-los antes do lançamento final.