# Como fazer o versionamento de software baseado nas recomendações da Microsoft?

Tags: versionamento, microsoft

Bom já vi muito sobre o versionamento semântico: ***Major, Minor e Patch***. Porém algo muito curioso é o versionamento de software recomendado pela Microsoft: ***Major, Minor, Build, Revision***.

Agora as perguntas:

- Como funciona cada um deles?
- quando devo implementar um acréscimo no número? (ex: quando fizer qualquer modificação em um arquivo, quando fixar algo, etc...)
- Qual a vantagem em utilizar esse tipo de versionamento ao invés do semântico?
- (opcional) pra que tipos de aplicações esse versionamento se é recomendado?

Eu não quero saber a opinião de como acha que se versiona desta maneira, mas sim como realmente se dever fazer e usar isto de acordo como a Microsoft recomenda. Tentei procurar e pesquisar várias vezes...fuçar o Google mas não encontrei, então achei que alguém daqui poderia saber dizer!

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou amigo, mas acho que esta resposta deve ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114287/3635

Comment: Já que a pergunta é bem específica acho que só respostas que possam indicar uma fonte serão válidas. A pergunta não é sobre como cada um faz, é sobre como o Microsoft faz. Senão cai na opinião.

Comment: @bigown é meio que isso, tipo eu não quero saber a opinião do povo e sim realmente como se deve fazer e usar isso de acordo como a Microsoft recomenda. Pois eu seguindo essa base ainda acho que não faço da maneira correta. Tentei procurar e pesquisar várias vezes...fuçar o Google mas não encontrei, então achei que alguém daqui poderia saber!

Answer (score 0):

O versionamento é específico de cada projeto, é definido pela equipe. Depende dos objetivos e da metodologia de desenvolvimento (a metodologia influencia nos ciclos, se é que o projeto tem ciclos). Essas coisas são abertas, existem vários modelos mas cada equipe costuma usar variações, criando o seu próprio. De *oficial* só tem os conceitos básicos (major, minor, build etc)

Acho que não faz sentido existir uma recomendação da Microsoft por conta disso.

Comment: Então poxa....Aqui não pode debater por conta das bases em opiniões, desse modo nunca vai poder existir uma pergunta sobre versionamento de software sem apenas explicações dos significados das palavras e sua hierarquia....

Comment: Parece-me apropriado, pois é totalmente subjetivo. A regra em si não é tão relevante, o importante é manter a consistência. Mas quando vemos as mudanças no esquema de versionamento do Mac OS e do Firefox, percebemos que nem consistência é tão relevante também.

Comment: então você acha que pode fazer se for esse tipo de pergunta?

Comment: Na verdade, achei apropriado _não poder_ fazer esse tipo de pergunta aqui haha. Justamente por ser totalmente subjetivo.