# O que significa o teste alfa, teste beta e produção no Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo meu primeiro aplicativo e quando fui fazer upload para o Google Play Developer Console fiquei em dúvida em qual área faço o upload pois aparece 3 opções: Teste Alfa, Teste Beta e Produção.

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: [Como se decide se uma aplicação está em alfa, beta, RC ou RTM?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20999/91)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Não há muita diferença entre os testes alfa e beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984120/need-some-clarification-about-beta-alpha-testing-on-the-developer-console) exceto pelo fato que você começa com um grupo pequeno para os testes alfa e passa para um grupo maior para os testes beta.

Produção é o termo que se usa quando seu aplicativo está disponível para seus usuários finais, aqueles para os quais você fabricou o aplicativo (ou seja, quando está disponível para qualquer um baixar ou comprar na Play Store).

Para fazer os testes alfa e beta você precisa enviar convites para os interessados em suas contas Google+ de forma que eles possam acessar seu aplicativo e baixá-lo. Os convites costumam ter a forma de um link direcionando-os para seu aplicativo na Play Store, que só fica visível para eles quando eles tiverem aceito o convite.

Do [Google Developer Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=pt-BR):

> **Como eu começo?**
>
> Recomendamos começar com um pequeno grupo de
>   testadores Alfa e, em seguida, expandir seu teste para um grupo de
>   teste Beta maior.
>
> **Devo usar testes Beta abertos ou fechados?**
>
> **Beta fechado:** use esta
>   opção se quiser realizar um teste com um grupo menor (como em sua
>   empresa ou equipe) ou quando você souber exatamente com quais usuários
>   deseja testar seu app. Se você testar um app já publicado, somente os
>   usuários no seu grupo de testes receberão uma atualização da versão
>   Alfa/Beta.
>
> **Beta aberto:** use esta opção se quiser realizar um teste com um grupo
>   grande e exibir a versão Beta do seu app na Play Store. Se você
>   realizar um teste Beta aberto, qualquer pessoa poderá participar do
>   seu programa Beta e enviar comentários privados para você. Verifique
>   se o app está pronto para ficar visível na Play Store antes de
>   escolher essa opção.
>
> As versões Beta abertas e fechadas do seu app não terão avaliações
>   públicas.